# LaTeX changes colour of in-text citing with hyperref package and natbib

Tags: latex, hyperref

I am using the [natbib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) and [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) packages in my LaTeX document and would like to change the colour of the box around the hyper-referenced citations from the baseline green to a more muted colour (violet or navy blue). However, in using the suggested code to do this, I cannot get the citation link colours to change. MWE:

```
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 colorlinks=false,
 citecolor=Violet,
 linkcolor=Red,
 urlcolor=Blue}

 \begin{document}

 \bibliographystyle{apsr}
 \bibliography{exp_final}
 \end{document}
```

However, when I compile (I compiled multiple times to make sure) my pdf file looks the same as if I had excluded the formatting in the `\hypersetup` (still the same green). I would also like to box the footnote citations as well.

Comment: You have a double `\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}` command in your code sample. You can safely remove one of them -- I suppose it's a copy/paste error.

Answer (score 42):

Actually the sample code you provided deactivate the link colorisation with the option `colorlinks=false`. You should use the following hyperref setup command that actually change links color.

```
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  citecolor=Violet,
  linkcolor=Red,
  urlcolor=Blue}
```

To change box color around the links and citations, you have these other options :

```
\hypersetup{
  citebordercolor=Violet,
  filebordercolor=Red,
  linkbordercolor=Blue
}
```

Box appearance (specifically, width of PDF link border) is controlled by the `pdfborder` option. If the `colorlinks` option is set, boxes are deactivated (see the [hyperref manual](http://www-control.eng.cam.ac.uk/~pcr20/latex/hyperref.pdf) for more information).

Comment: I forgot to mention some weirdness about these options. I remember deactivating boxes (by setting the border width to 0) and it worked but only using Acrobat Reader (any OS). The boxes were still visible when using xpdf or evince as I usually do.

Comment: Lohrun,


Thanks!

However, I found that the color format should be RGB: so it should be
     \hypersetup{
  citebordercolor=.1 .1 1,
  linkbordercolor=0 0 1,
  urlbordercolor=.9 .1 0, 
}

Thanks though!
Thomas

Comment: Actually, color names work just fine. 

Also, please consider accepting the answer as correct if it worked.

Comment: info: capitalized `urlcolor=Blue` did *not* work for me in usepackage option call. `urlcolor=blue` did work.

Comment: Link to hyperref manual not working anymore. Also I'm getting errors with Blue, blue, or even 0 0 1, or .1 . 1 .1 or .9 .1 0, or Red or red or Violet or violet.

Comment: these settings aren't working, link to documentation is broken