# Latex \hyperref not changing the color of citations

Tags: latex, org-mode

This question is based on this [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770347/latex-changes-colour-of-in-text-citing-with-hyperref-package-and-natbib#2771475) question. According to the answer given,

```
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  citecolor=Violet,
  linkcolor=Red,
  urlcolor=Blue}
```

it is possible to change the color of citations.  However, when I do that, I am not getting any color.  Everything is looking black. I tried many permutations to the answer like `colorlinks=true`, `colorlinks=false`, removing the field `colorlinks` altogether, but every time, I am getting the same black color.

Am I to add the package `xcolor` in order to work this?  Can anyone help me.

I am using `org-mode` to write the document and exporting to PDF using `org-latex-export`.

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Comment: I agree, I should produce a minimal reproducible code.  Sorry for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't show any useable code, but if I were to guess, I'd say you did not define the non-standard colour names with capital letters. Either define them or use standard names from one of the color packages, e.g. from `xcolor`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  citecolor=violet,
  linkcolor=red,
  urlcolor=blue}


\begin{document}


\url{URL}

\end{document}
```